# How to draw part of image in Maui.Graphics

Tags: c#, image, graphics, maui, crop

In the `IDrawable Drawable` property of a `MAUI.GraphicsView`, I want to draw **a part** of an image. That is a sub rectangle of the original image.

Problem: I can't find a way nor to crop an `IImage` returned by `PlatformImage.FromStream(stream)` nor to draw only a part of an `IImage`, with something like this function of Skiasharp but for `Maui.GraphicsView`:

```
public void DrawImage(SkiaSharp.SKImage image, SkiaSharp.SKRect source, SkiaSharp.SKRect dest);
```

Can somebody propose a way to achieve this?

Just to be extensive, here is the code I want to extend:

```cs
    public class GraphicsDrawable : IDrawable
    {
        public double Scale { get; set; }
        public Point Center { get; set; }
        public Rect DisplayedRect { get; set; }
    
        private Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.IImage image;
    
        public GraphicsDrawable()
        {
            // Load image
            Assembly assembly = GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
            using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("BOBMaui.Resources.Images.bobstart.jpg"))
            {
                image = PlatformImage.FromStream(stream);
            }
        }
    
        public void Draw(ICanvas canvas, RectF containerRect)
        {
            if (image != null)
            {
                // Anyway, the output will be displayed on containerRect size which is the full size of the container
    
                // STEP 1 - Computes the clipping to apply to image
                // Computes scaled size which is the size of the part of the image to be displayed
                double scaledWidth = image.Width / Scale;
                double scaledHeight = image.Height / Scale;
    
                // Computes horizontal coordinates
                double xCenterImageOUT = Center.X * image.Width;
                double xLeft = Math.Max(0, xCenterImageOUT - scaledWidth/2);  // May not be negative
                double xRight = Math.Min(xCenterImageOUT + scaledWidth / 2, image.Width);  // May not extend outside base image
                if (xRight - xLeft < scaledWidth)
                {
                    // One of the border was forced to 0 or image.Width
                    if (xLeft == 0) xRight = scaledWidth;
                    else xLeft = image.Width - scaledWidth;
                }
    
                // Computes vertical coordinates
                double yCenterImageOUT = Center.Y * image.Height;
                double yTop = Math.Max(0, yCenterImageOUT - scaledHeight / 2);  // May not be negative
                double yBottom = Math.Min(yCenterImageOUT + scaledHeight / 2, image.Height);  // May not extend outside base image
                if (yBottom - yTop < scaledHeight)
                {
                    // One of the border was forced to 0 or image.Width
                    if (yTop == 0) yBottom = scaledHeight;
                    else yBottom = image.Height - scaledHeight;
                }
                // Define clipping rectangle
                DisplayedRect = new Rect(xLeft, yTop, scaledWidth, scaledHeight);
    
                // STEP 2 - Paint the canvas
                // There is the problem - I need to crop the image before drawing it
                // Sthg like:  canvas.DrawImage(image, source: DisplayRect, dest: containerRect);
                canvas.DrawImage(image, containerRect.X, containerRect.Y, containerRect.Width, containerRect.Height);
            }
    
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

> image is of type Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.IImage which doesn't declare
> a clip function. It comes from image =
> PlatformImage.FromStream(stream);

Then you can use method `path.AppendRectangle` to achieve this.

Please refer to the following code:

```
  public class ClippingDrawable : IDrawable
    {
        public void Draw(ICanvas canvas, RectF dirtyRect)
        {
            IImage image;
            var assembly = GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
            using (var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("GraphicsViewDemos.Resources.Images.dotnet_bot.png"))
            {
                image = PlatformImage.FromStream(stream);
            }

            if (image != null)
            {    
                PathF path = new PathF();
                path.AppendRectangle(60, 60, 90, 90); 
                canvas.ClipPath(path);  // Must be called before DrawImage
                canvas.DrawImage(image, 10, 10, image.Width, image.Height);


            }
        }
    }
```

Note:

1.For more information, please check document: [GraphicsView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/graphicsview?view=net-maui-8.0).

You can also check the official sample here: [GraphicsViewDemos](https://github.com/dotnet/maui-samples/tree/main/8.0/UserInterface/Views/GraphicsViewDemos).
The above sample code has the effect you want. Please pay attention to [DrawShapesPage.xaml](https://github.com/dotnet/maui-samples/blob/main/8.0/UserInterface/Views/GraphicsViewDemos/GraphicsViewDemos/Views/DrawShapesPage.xaml).

2.in Maui, you could use `Clip` property to crop image on MAUI.

For instance, you could use the following code to crop the image:

```
var clip1 = new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(100, 100, 100, 100));  
image.Clip = clip1;
```

Please refer to [Clip with a Geometry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/shapes/geometries?view=net-maui-7.0#clip-with-a-geometry) to get more details.

Comment: Hi, I saw this information. But, I do not understand it. image is of type Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.IImage which doesn't declare a clip function. It comes from image = PlatformImage.FromStream(stream);

Comment: Hi Jessie, I also look at your suggestion before posting but due to this BUG https://github.com/dotnet/Microsoft.Maui.Graphics/issues/405 it do not work. I can give you access to this repos if you want to try it out.

Comment: I tried the official sample, and it could work properly on my side. :)

Comment: Jessie, I'm really sorry but I can't understand how you make your code working. The line "IImage image;" can't be compiled on my side because it says 'Ambigous reference between Microsoft.maui.graphics.IImage' and 'Microsoft.Maui.IImage'. How can it be that you do not get the same message ? I have to force "Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.IImage image;" to get compiled. Can you share your repo ?

Comment: To be complete, I also need to change to compiler action from "MAUI Image" to "Embebed resource".